# year dropdown section being stored as null

Tags: php, cakephp

I couldn't think of a decent title - hopefully it's clear enough.
Right, I was originally having a problem with creating a year dropdown selector in a registration form - which does now work but the value stored in the database remains null even when selecting a year (I have left this as optional for registrations).

Here is the code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('graduation1', array('label' => 'Year of Graduation:',
                                                             'type' => 'date',
                                                             'dateFormat' => 'Y',
                                                             'empty' => true,
                                                             'minYear' => 1960, // start year
                                                             'maxYear' => date('Y') // current 
                                                            )
                                      );
```

Thanks to the community for the help in advance!

Controller code:

```
function register() {
            $this->layout = 'login';
            $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Member Registration');
            if(!empty($this->data)) {
                      $this->data['User']['group_id'] = 4;
                      $this->User->create();
                         if($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                            $this->set('user', $this->data['User']['id']);
                            $this->_sendEmail('register', 'A new registration has been submitted', 'blah@blah.com');
                            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'approval'));
                        } else {
                            unset($this->data['User']['password']);
                            unset($this->data['User']['password_confirm']);
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('There were errors found in your registration.  Please check the highlighted fields', true));
                    }
            }               
        }
```

HTMl output:

```
<div id="grad">
        <label>Year of Graduation:</label>
        <select name="data[User][graduation1][year]" id="UserGraduation1Year">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
</select>        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @andreas Controller code has been added to the original post.  Thanks for your prompt response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `$this->User->create()`, try `var_dump($this->data)` to make sure that `graduation1` is indeed get POSTed, if it does, make sure that the field in your table is called `graduation1`

-- EDIT --

If you only want to store a single integer (a year), just use int as the field datatype instead of date

-- EDIT2 --
Not sure why cakephp generates `name="data[User][graduation1][year]"` try

```
$yearRanges = range(1960, date("Y"));
echo $this->Form->input('User.graduation1', array('label' => 'Year of Graduation:',
                                                             'type' => 'select',
                                                             'options' => array_combine($yearRanges, $yearRanges),
                                                             'empty' => true
                                                            )
                                      );
```

Comment: Everything checks out and the dump gives ["graduation1"]=> array(1) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2005" }...  Still coming up as null in the database

Comment: graduation1 is a datetime field in your database? That might be the problem

Comment: Which cakephp version are you using? I fail to find type => date input in either 1.3 or 2.0

Comment: The field name in the database was originally datetime but I changed it recently to date to see if that made any difference.  Value being stored is still NULL..  I am not seasoned with php - still on a learning curve.

Comment: Do you have a live example page I could go look at?

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for helping me out on this - unfortunately the site is not live yet.  I have added the html output from the form  - is that sufficient?  Another question, should I leave the database field name as datetime or?

Comment: changed field type to int and get this error: Array to string conversion. With your changes the html output is still : <select name="data[User][graduation1][year]" id="UserGraduation1Year">

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Comment: great it's moved a step forward now - html output is : <select name="data[User][graduation1]" id="UserGraduation1">. when selecting 1973 for instance, 13 is being stored in the database.  The html for 1973 is : <option value="13">1973</option>

Comment: eidted my answer. I think that should do it :)